# Role of dynamicAllocation and executorAllocationRatio

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to understand the role of executorAllocationRatio. If we have below spark configurations set for a job running on a cluster,

```
"spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled": "true", 
"spark.dynamicAllocation.executorAllocationRatio": "0.4"
"spark.executor.cores": "5"
"spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors": "6"
"spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors": "30"
"spark.executor.instances": "30"
```

Behaviour with above configs:

- what is the minimum number of executor and cores allocated to a job to start with? Is it 6 executors , 5 cores/executor (ie total 6*5=30 cores) or executorAllocationRatio has any role to play with?
- when we dynamicAllocation is enabled, does it impact on cores? ie. is 5 the minimum cores/executor or cores/executor can also be lower than 5?

Comment: If [Spark's own documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#dynamic-allocation) is not clear, perhaps you can file a doc jira (see how in the "contributing" section).

Comment: I have went through the Spark doc earlier before posting, though I was able to follow what dynamicAllocation is, however could not follow about ratio with combination of above configs. Hence posted specific question to understand more on this. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On an unconstrained cluster, the answer to the first part ("what is the minimum number of executor and cores allocated to a job to start with?") will be 30 executors, 5 cores each = 150 cores.  `executorAllocationRatio` won't have bearing on this number. However, if resources are scarce, you may see your application start scheduling before the whole initial demand is satisfied, based on `spark.scheduler.maxRegisteredResourcesWaitingTime` and `spark.scheduler.minRegisteredResourcesRatio` settings as described in [Spark Config - Scheduling](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#scheduling) section.

Second part of your question is simple -- 5 is neither minimum nor maximum, its the exact number of cores allocated for each executor.

`spark.dynamicAllocation.executorAllocationRatio=1` (default) means that Spark will try to allocate `P executors = 1.0 * N tasks / T cores` to process  N pending tasks. The ratio `X` less than 1.0 will lower the number of requested executors by the factor of `X`. This setting does not affect or consider runtime resource availability. The other way to look at it is that by default Spark will request new executor for every pending task staying in the queue for the duration of `spark.dynamicAllocation.schedulerBacklogTimeout` or `spark.dynamicAllocation.sustainedSchedulerBacklogTimeout`. The ratio X < 1 will allow it to request new executor for every `1/X` tasks.

Comment: got it. As far the first question,  on a constrained cluster, what would be the role of executorAllocationRatio with above mentioned config values?

Comment: I added last para to my answer. Hope it helps!

Comment: just thinking through on this, how config executorAllocationRatio even helps? because number of executor to be allocated is decided based on, number of tasks to cores in each executor. so if there are 5 cores in each executor,40 tasks in total, so eventually spark needs 40/5= 8 executor. Trying to follow how executorAllocationRatio is relevant. So if we set executorAllocationRatio to 0.4, does this mean spark starts with (0.4 * 8 executor) 3 executor and scales up until total 8 executors?

Comment: As doc says. _"While this [default 1.0] minimizes the latency of the job, with small tasks this setting can waste a lot of resources due to executor allocation overhead, as some executor might not even do any work. This setting allows to set a ratio that will be used to reduce the number of executors w.r.t. full parallelism."_ It won't scale to 8, the expectation being that 3 executors will be able to process all 40 tasks (in three batches of 15) faster/more efficient than spinning extra executors.

Comment: got it. In that case can we not directly set max executor to 3, why do we need executorAllocationRatio? because if know the value of executorAllocationRatio prior, we can also estimate max executor.

Comment: You can if you know total number of tasks will always be 40. What if you don't? (Sidebar -- this is enough comments for one post.)