# Dynamic Resource Allocation

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

As per the [spark documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#:%7E:text=By%20default%2C%20the,dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors%20settings), `spark.dynamicAllocation.executorAllocationRatio` does the following:

> By default, the dynamic allocation will request enough executors to maximize the parallelism according to the number of tasks to process. While this minimizes the latency of the job, with small tasks this setting can waste a lot of resources due to executor allocation overhead, as some executor might not even do any work.

From the [Google docs](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc-serverless/docs/concepts/autoscaling), `executorAllocationRatio` does the following:

> Customizes scaling up of the Spark workload. Accepts a value from 0 to 1. A value of 1.0 provides maximum scale-up capability and helps achieve maximum parallelism. A value of 0.5 sets scale-up capability and parallelism at one-half the max value.

**Query**:

- if the default behaviour is to allocate enough executors based on the task, what is the relevance of `spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors` and `maxExecutors`? is it just to ensure job does not cross min and max executor threshold, and has no role to play other than this? Also why "some executor might not even do any work" as mentioned in the doc above.

My initial understanding of dynamicAllocation was that, spark allocates executors based on `spark.dynamicAllocation.initialExecutors` (this can be overridden if we also set `spark.executor.instances`). Later spark scales up based on resources need upto maxExecutors.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Role of dynamicAllocation and executorAllocationRatio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77154895/role-of-dynamicallocation-and-executorallocationratio)

Comment: the shared link covers the question specifically on allocationRation. Hence posted new with specific question.

Comment: Your question is at least partially about how `executorAllocationRatio` works. Which the link explains. You also neglected to post a key piece of information from the official docs, which further explains when `executorAllocationRatio` is used and when min/max executors are used instead. The question question above and the documentation you neglected to post answer the question.

Comment: are you referring to mention in the doc "The target number of executors computed by the dynamicAllocation can still be overridden by the spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors and spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors settings"?,  If yes, above question is still relevant .  If not , can you point to specific section you are talking about, I could not find and might have missed. thanks